# SSDT MongoDB SSIS

Tags: mongodb, sql-server-data-tools, drivers

I am trying to create a SSDT -SSIS package for MongoDB to Azure SQL DW and I created a project in SSDT and add MongoDB Drivers. But I am not able to add these reference to the gacutil and having issues such as

"Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.4.1.18, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk."

Also I tried to add install it in cmd as admin I am getting a "need to strong name assembly error"

Any help/directions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that your warning specifies `processorArchitecture=MSIL`.  Try changing the processor architecture of your project to x86 or x64 to match that of your Mongo DLLs.